# Как вывести картинку из скрипта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, функции

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
var randomNumber;
randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1));
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML=randomNumber;
}
```

Как в этом коде сделать так, чтобы когда, например, генерируется число 1, вместо числа появлялась картинка?

Comment: Да, ну например сгенерировалась цифра "1" и я хочу, чтобы не просто цифра была , а картинка этой цифры.

Comment: просто 1.png и все

Comment: и таких 6 штук, то есть 1.png 2. png и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужна картинка с сервера, то вот так:

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
  let  randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1));
  let img = `<img src="${randomNumber}.png">`;
  document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = img;
  console.log(img )
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
<button id="button">rnd</button>
```

Comment: Картинка просто в папке с файлами html, css, js